# Will upgrading mysql server on one machine affect connection to another machine?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

I have a web server set up on machine TXAP1. My mysql server is set up on another machine called TXDATA.

I also have a test mysql server on TXAP1. I am going to use it to upgrade the version of mysql to test the upgrade process.

Will upgrading the version of mysql on TXAP1 affect the ability to connect to the mysql server on TXDATA?

```
OS: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11
Apache: 2.2.10
PHP: 5.2.6
MySQL: 5.0.67
```

Comment: It shouldn't have any affect as long as you keep your connections straight.

Comment: Your mysql server is very outdated. The latest version is 5.7+. The same is true with PHP also. The latest version is 5.6 and for apache it is 2.4+

Comment: Yes I know, we are working on upgrading these

Answer (score 0):

> Will upgrading the version of mysql on TXAP1 affect the ability to connect to the mysql server on TXDATA?

Well, no. Connection to the TXDATA MySQL server will never be affected. However, you won't be able to use new mysql functions on the TXDATA for obvious reasons